# Дискорд бот не подключается к голосовому каналу

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.6, youtube, youtube-dl

*Попытался написать код для дискорд бота который берет музыку с ютуба и проигрывает. Cам бот запускается и работает, но на префиксы никак не реагирует, хотя проверял что все права ему выданы.*

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online')

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client.is_playing():
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
            'quiet': True,
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
            voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, executable="ffmpeg.exe"), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(info['title']))
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is already playing")

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш бот не может реагировать на префиксы, т.к. не видит контент сообщений.

Включите **message_content**:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```